# How to convert YYYYMM to YYYY-MM-01 using Azure data factory expression

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to convert the YYYYMM to YYYY-MM-01 using azure data factory pipeline expression.

I tried the below expression but it giving me error that date value should follow the ISO 8601 format.

```html
@formatDateTime(concat('202301','01'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

It should return in this format '2023-01-01'.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used multiple substring to get this as shown below, if any better answer please let me know.

```html
@concat(substring(concat('202301','01'),0,4 ),'-',substring(concat('202301','01'),4,2),'-',substring(concat('202301','01'),6,2))
```

Comment: I think you can just supply yyyy-MM-01 as an argument to the format function - let me know if you need me to check

Comment: @wBob it doesn't work throwing the same error ISO 8601 format.

Comment: Just in case if some one want to solve this in SQL server, use this  SELECT Convert(Date,'202301'+'01')

Comment: @SQL006 thank you for that tip!  Worked when nothing else would.  SELECT convert(Date, YYYYMM_column + '01')

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a format string including numbers to `formatDateTime`, for example:

```
@formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy-MM-01')
```

NB You have the case of your argument wrong, it should be lower-case y for Year, upper-case M for month and lower-case d for Day.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating 202301 with 01 (three times) and then taking substring, you can use the below expression to achieve the same.

```sql
@concat(substring('202301',0,4 ),'-',substring('202301',4,2),'-','01')
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just a simpler way , then what you have used.

```
@concat(substring('202301',0,4),'-',substring('202301',4,2),'-01')
```

[image]

The issue here is the

```
@formatDateTime(string(concat('202301','01')),'YYYYMMDD' ) does not work
```

is missing the "-" but

```
@formatDateTime(string(concat('2023-01','-01')),'yyyyMMdd' )
```

Just works fine.

I am not sure as to what is the Source here , if it is query then you can get the yyyymm in the form of yyyy-mm and that should help .

Also I request to have a look on the startOfMonth function .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#startOfMonth